# Create a PDF or Printable version of change_list.html in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, pdf-generation

I would like to add a tool link at the top of my admin change_list.html, which I have already done, and have this link basically be able to produce some sort of printable document version of my models data based off of my current filter settings. Basically a print button in the admin change_list.html.

so far I have overridden the change_list.html to create the link, and I notice that this

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}" class="addlink">
      {% blocktrans %}View PDF{% endblocktrans %}
    </a>
  </li>
```

gives you a link based on these choices.. but Im kinda lost as to the best/easiest way to do this..

Sorry, new to Django. I know I can use ReportLabs to generate pdfs, but not a 100% on how to get the filtered data from change_list to it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but for those who might be searching "in the future" like me, this might be helpful: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1842/